# How can I install Ubuntu with APT (not Snappy) on the Raspberry Pi 2?

Tags: system-installation, raspberrypi, ubuntu-core

http://www.raspberrypi.org/downloads/ lists only a Snappy Ubuntu Core image for the Noobs OS installer.

Is it possible to install a traditional Ubuntu OS, featuring apt-get together with the standard repositories (so not Snappy Ubuntu), on the Raspberry Pi 2? Is a Noobs  image for this in the works?

Comment: Snappy does not use apt-get. I think Raspbian is closer to what you want.

Comment: @Jos: well yes, I am asking for non-Snappy Ubuntu. I edited the question for clarity.

Comment: In waiting for my Pi 2 to come in, but from what I understand you need to install with a netinstall image. - - edit: I assumed server, cause that what I want. Not sure about desktop edition

Comment: Install APT's dependencies manually, copy APT database from Ubuntu Core ARM database, install APT and voilá.

Comment: @Erkin: I don't think you can install apt-get at all on Snappy Ubuntu Core: https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/

Comment: There is also a community image [here, with all instructions on what you might want to install/configure as well](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi)

Comment: @Leo: this is great, why don't you post this as an Answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

User [leo](https://askubuntu.com/users/390453/leo) submitted a great answer as a [comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/583429/how-can-i-install-ubuntu-with-apt-not-snappy-on-the-raspberry-pi-2#comment836453_583429), I am reposting it here for convenience:

> There is also a community image [here, with all instructions on what you might want to install/configure as well](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ARM/RaspberryPi)

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so here is the link for netinstall of Ubuntu Desktop 
[armhf Ubuntu 14.04](http://ports.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-ports/dists/trusty-updates/main/installer-armhf/current/images/generic-lpae/netboot/)

For more info check out [guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/NetbootInstallFromInternet)

Can't go any further till I get mine, plus I'm going to install a server install.

Comment: How does any of this relate to a Raspberry Pi 2? As far as I can tell, OS installation for a Raspberry Pi involves writing an OS image on an SD card from another PC, then booting the Pi with the SD...

Comment: Yes, you would put the files on SD. From what I read, they go into /boot directory. Not sure if just have to restart at that point or if there more too it. I been researching topic, but at standstill till mine come in. We may have to check out the raspbian-ua-netinstall source on GitHub for some clues how to achieve.

Comment: Quoting from the guide you posted: "You need to have grub or grub2 already installed and bootable in order to use this method". I don't think this is the case with the Raspberry Pi.

Comment: I missed that... Sorry.  I still think the answer is going to be similar to raspbian-ua-netinstall. May need to wait on them, or someone else.

Comment: Ugh. Mine won't ship till 2/19 (I ordered 2/2) but I guess it better than original ship date of 2/24

Answer (score 0):

All nonsense - of course you can run Ubuntu on Pi!

There is Ubuntu 14.4.2, compiled for armhf (for the Pi 2, at least).  You can write it to your SD card using Apple Pi-Baker for Mac (go find your own, Windows users!).

It instantly loads to the login page (ubuntu, ubuntu being the default user and password).

You can upgrade that image to at least Ubuntu 15.04, if you wish.

That is all for Ubuntu server, of course.  If you want Ubuntu desktop, try the Mate image, currently compiled up to Ubuntu 15.10.

In closing, the ENTIRE point of Ubuntu Snappy is to standardise and simplify installations specifically excluding tools like apt-get.